# Can you use Ethereum to build a blockchain with a different proof mechanism?

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work

This may be a silly question but is it possible to build a system that can use both the euthereum proof of work/stake and a custom built proof using the same ethereum nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Proof-of-Work algorithm used in Ethereum right now is [ETHash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash).

To implement some custom sort of algorithm you would have to fork and modify the original source.

It is unclear why you would want to do this as you would be on your own chain and not part of the existing network.